# Why Can't I Create a Base Station File on Trimble GeoXT?

Tags: trimble

I am trying to create a base station file to log data on a Trimble GeoXT (GeoExplorer 2008 Series). We are mapping buildings at this location. After entering in all necessary information (antenna settings, logging interval, Min SNR, Min Elevation, and then the Lat/Long/Altitude), It is not allowing me to move on to the next screen to log data (the 'OK' button is grayed out). I have tried various ways to enter the Lat/Long/Altitude info (degree/minute/second signs or none, no spaces/with spaces, N and W or a minus sign (-)). I have made sure that the format matches that found in the Trimble unit/coordinate system setup. The location information I am using is from an on-ground survey control found here:

https://apps.larimer.org/survey-control-network/Ranger.htm

I have also tried hooking up an external GPS receiver (Hurricane P/N 50393-50) or using the internal device GPS. Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: I guess you are using TerraSync? If so, what version are you using and what edition do you have (this information should be available on TerraSync Status / About screen)?

Comment: @Trams It is Version 4.00 and the Professional edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following:

- Work in a location where your GeoExplorer gets a GPS position
- Go through the TerraSync base file creation procedure (as you have done already)
- On the final Base File Logging Settings screen, instead of trying to enter Lat, Long, Alt, tap the "Here" button - that should populate the Latitude / Longitude / Altitude fields
- Edit the Lat / Long / Alt which TerraSync gave to change those to your base position (they should be pretty close to the "here" values).  Make sure you don't change the format!

NOTE: I have TerraSync 5.90 on a Geo 7x - this wants me to enter Base Position in Northings and Eastings, even though I have Display format set to Latitude / Longitude.  I think this is a TerraSync bug.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I had thought it wouldn't need a GPS position since all the guide examples showed '0' satellites, but it seems like that was all that was needed. The format is provided with 'Here' and I just changed the base position. Thanks, again!